# Prossess state getting in c under window plateform

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am using CreateProcess function for creating the process, is there any option to get the current state of the process (running or not). Kindly guide me how can I make it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OpenProcess` function with that dwProcessId if it returns NULL Process is not running otherwise it will return handle to that process

Comment: Why do you call OpenProcess? It only gives you another handle to the new process, as CreateProcess already returned one.

Comment: I guess OpenProcess Will not create new process it will return handle only if that process is running (I am not sure...)

Answer (score 1):

Create process returns a handle to the process in PROCESS_INFORMATION structure, you can use this with something like [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx) to work out if it is still running, or you can use the wait functions to wait for it to exit.